# Flash Socket HTTP-POST Example

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets, https, http-post

This article provides an example of using the flash.net.Socket class to connect to a socket:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/Socket.html

The example at the bottom shows how to use an HTTP-GET request.

**I need to use an HTTP-POST request.**

Bonus: Does this work with HTTPS port 443?

Answer (score 2):

The Socket is not the correct class for this job. Sockets are used for working with raw TCP data connections.  For example, you would use Socket to integrate with custom server component that uses a proprietary communications protocol.

Instead, use the [URLRequest class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html) to perform HTTP requests from flash/actionscript.  This class supports POST as well as GET.  It also supports HTTPS.

[Here](http://www.hardcode.nl/archives_9/article_442-post-request-data-in-as3.htm) is an example of doing a POST request.  (incidentally, that is the first result google gives when you search for ["as3 post request"](http://www.google.com/search?gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=as3+post+request))

There are also examples available in the documentation (linked above), and other places around the net.

---

**Edit:** To retrieve binary streaming data from an HTTP server, you *should* use [URLStream](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLStream.html).  Something like the following will accomplish this via a POST request:

```
private var stream:URLStream;
private var uploadData:ByteArray;

public function URLStreamExample() {
    stream = new URLStream();
    stream.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, progressHandler);

    var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("URLStreamExample.swf");
    request.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

    // uploadData contains the data to send with the post request
    // set the proper content type for the data you're sending
    request.contentType = "application/octet-stream";
    request.data = uploadData;  

    // initiate the request
    stream.load(request);
}

private function progressHandler(event:Event):void {
    // called repeatedly as data arrives (just like Socket's progress event)

    // URLStream is an IDataInput (just like Socket)
    while( stream.bytesAvailable ) {
       var b:int = stream.readByte();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am connecting to a socket to retrieve streaming data. The data is binary. It IS the correct class and is already working using HTTP-GET. I just need to use HTTP-POST since I will be sending large amounts of data to the socket server.

Comment: The problem with using plain sockets is that you will need to properly encode the POSTed data as per the HTTP spec. This might be doable, but unless you need to do something special, it's probably more trouble then it's worth. You can post binary data using URLRequest by assigning a ByteArray into the .data property of the URLRequest. This, by the way will also give you HTTPS access (port 443) for free.

Comment: Well... HTTP is a protocol for communicating on top of TCP sockets, so of course you can build the protocol code yourself if you want to.  HTTP is defined by [RFC 2616](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616).  Description of the http request structure begins on [page 35](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#page-35).  Discusson of the [POST] method is on [page 54](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-9.5).  HTTPS (a.k.a. "HTTP over TLS") is defined by [RFC-2818](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2818).

Comment: I'm asking because I have a VERY SPECIFIC need. I already use URLRequest to POST some data for login. Now I NEED to use POST with flash.net.Socket.

Comment: well, the RFC's linked above should give you enough information to accomplish that.  You'll need to send the proper RequestLine, which will look something like `POST /path/to/resource.mov HTTP/1.1`, followed by the necessary headers (of which there are numerous possibilities, depending on your *specific needs*).  Follow that with an empty line (CRLF), and finally your post data (which must match the headers you sent, especially content-type and content-length).  HTTPS is *much* more complicated, so you're on your own there. (or, check my edit above for a streaming example using URLRequest).

Comment: I am asking for a basic example of that:

Comment: If you've already got a GET request working, then what's the big deal? Change `"GET"` to `"POST"` in the Request Line, and give it a try. (it'll probably work).  Then you can build up from there: add content to the post body, add the appropriate headers (Content-Length, and Content-Type at minimum).  HTTP is just human-readable text, so download a web debug proxy (like [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/)), capture some real post requests (from your browser), and look at the raw protocol data that is sent. You're going to have to do some of the work yourself.